# cast a column in a Spark Dataset to custom UDT

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, casting, apache-spark-dataset

Suppose I have a UDT, defined as DataTypes.ErrorType. Error is a class which contains a String variable. Now I want to do

```
df.select(columnName).cast(DataTypes.ErrorType), where
df =Dataset<Row>
columnname= Name of a String column in the dataset.
```

When I try to do that following error I get: cannot resolve 'CAST(`year` AS STRUCT-`error`- STRING-)' due to data type mismatch- cannot cast StringType to ErrorType.

Bellow is the detail of the ErrorType:

```
class ErrorType extends UserDataTypes<Error>{... overridden methods}

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = ErrorType.class)
class Error implements Serializable{
 private String name; 
//Getter and Setters
//Constructors
}
```

Is it possible to cast the column into my specified UDT. (Java preferred,  Scala will also do.).

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Comment: @Jacek: spark 2.11.

Comment: @AnupamRakshit Did you get resolution of this problem statement?